# MacOS: Commands working on terminal but not on iTerm

Tags: bash, terminal, path, bashrc, iterm

I installed some packages like brew via terminal which altered `$PATH`. Now iTerm's `$PATH` is not same as terminal, causing CLI commands like `brew` not working on iTerm.

`echo $PATH` on terminal gives:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Users/avinashvarma/.rbenv/shims:/Users/avinashvarma/bin:/Users/avinashvarma/.rbenv/shims:/Users/avinashvarma/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin:/Users/avinashvarma/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/munki:/Users/avinashvarma/gocode/bin:/Users/avinashvarma/gocode/bin
```

`echo $PATH` on iTerm gives:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/avinashvarma/gocode/bin
```

I created a `$PATH` in `.bashrc` file but later deleted it and restarted system.

without the presence of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` no user-defined config should affect the shells.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you **[edit]** with more info? What version of macOS is this? In either Terminal or iTerm (it'll be the same), what is the output of `launchctl getenv PATH`, `cat /etc/paths`, `ls -lF /etc/paths.d`, `cat /etc/profile`, `cat /etc/bashrc`, `cat /etc/bash.bashrc`, `ls -ldF ~/.*bash*`, `cat ~/.bashrc`, `cat ~/.bash_profile`, `cat ~/.bash_login` and `cat ~/.profile`? Errors are expected; please include them. But please show output of these commands in *both* Terminal and iTerm, as the results *may* differ: `echo "$-"`, `shopt login_shell`, `echo "$0"`, `echo "$BASH"` and `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`.

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks for the help. but i just removed Iterm and installed again since it a recent install it worked